# Google foobar question 1, minion job handling

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, dictionary, oop

I recently got an invitation to google foobar. I am stuck on the first problem. The problem is to:
write a function called solution(data, n) that takes in a list of less than 100 integers and a number n, and returns that same list but with all of the numbers that occur more than n times removed entirely. The returned list should retain the same ordering as the original list - you don't want to mix up those carefully-planned shift rotations! For instance, if data was [5, 10, 15, 10, 7] and n was 1, solution(data, n) would return the list [5, 15, 7] because 10 occurs twice, and thus was removed from the list entirely.
It would be run on an Python 2.7.13 sandbox

I have written some code myself and tested it on a 2.7 python sandbox and even on my own IDE and it works fine, but when I verify it gives that it only passed two test (test 1 and test 3) and failed all the others. Please help me correct/improve the code.
Code:

```
 from collections import Counter


    def solution(data, n):
        if len(data) < 100:  # Makes sure that it is only accepting integers below 100 i.e till 99
            counter = Counter(data)  # This counts how many of each element there are
            for element, count in dict(counter).items():  # Loop through the elements and their counts
                if count > n:  # If the count for the element is greater than n
                    for _ in range(count):  # Repeat as many times as the count
                        data.remove(element) # Remove the element from the original list
        print(data)
        return data
       else:
            break
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code would immediately error because it is not indented properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` with a list comprehension to filter out any elements that occur `n` or more times

```
from collections import Counter
def solution(data, n):
    c = Counter(data)
    return [i for i in data if c[i] < n]
```